# IE issue focusing a dynamically added option in a select element with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

Well this was a fun one.

So I discovered an inconsistency in Internet Explorer 9 that drove me up a wall the other day. It worked in FireFox and Chrome to my dismay because as most web developers know script debugging with IE's developer tools is a blast!

I saw this when I was trying to dynamically add an option to a select element and then trying to focus that option. It seemed like IE was ignoring my calls to focus my new element. To help illustrate the issue I have two examples:

**First Scenario** (the one that doesn't work in IE)

I start with a select having two options:

```
<select id="select">
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
</select>
```

I then add a new option to the select with JQuery and try to select it using the `.attr()` method:

```
var $newOpt = $('<option>New Option</option>');
var $select = $('#select');
$select.prepend($newOpt);
$newOpt.attr('selected','selected');
```

In Firefox and Chrome this works as expected. My option is added to the select and then it is focused. However, in Internet Explorer the option is only appended, not focused. (See the demo below)

[First Scenario Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/WRgD7/)

**Second Scenario**

I start with a select with three options, focusing 'option 1' by default:

```
<select id="select">
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option id="new">New Option</option>
</select>
```

I use JQuery to focus the New Option:

```
var $newOpt = $('#new');
$newOpt.attr('selected','selected');
```

Interestingly enough this works in all three browsers: Internet Explorer 9, FireFox, and Chrome. (See the demo below)

[Second Scenario Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/APBHB/)

**Work-Around**

I eventually found a workaround that wasn't so obvious originally since I had a great deal of complexity surrounded this issue at the time. I ended up using:

```
$select.children().removeAttr('selected');
```

To remove all selected attributes from the select before trying to focus the newly added option.

[Work-Around Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/APBHB/)

**Question**

I've been searching the web and I haven't found this documented anywhere so I'm wondering. Is it a bug? If so, is it a bug with JQuery or Internet Explorer? If not, am I using the `attr()` method incorrectly?

If anyone could shed some light on this it would be great. Thanks!

Comment: It seems removing the attribute is the easiest way to do it, none of the answers below work in IE9, and you would think they tested their answers before posting them ?

Comment: @adeneo Dude it works in IE9.

Comment: @adeneo PSL's suggestion works just fine in IE9.

Comment: @PSL - yeah, that seems to work! Not sure if I like any better than the OP's solution, but it does work in IE9.

Comment: `$newOpt.prependTo('#select').siblings().prop('selected', false).end().prop('selected', true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `selectedIndex`.

```
$(function () {
    var $newOpt = $('<option>New Option</option>');
    $('#select').prepend($newOpt).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EXgf9/)

It seems like a long runnign [IE bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1641) not fixed in jquery.

This works in IE though

```
 $(function () {
    var newOpt = document.createElement('OPTION');
    newOpt.innerHTML = 'New Option';
    var select = document.getElementById('select');
    select.add(newOpt,select.options[0]);
    $('#select option:first').prop('selected', true);
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vs95W/)

#### [.add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535921%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 Not sure who downvoted this. Looks good to me! =) I'd be interested to find out why the code in scenario 1 doesn't work though...

Comment: @user1506980 Thanks. Hope downvoter comes back with evidence.. Atleast i could replicate it in IE9 WIn 7 though.

Comment: Updated the answer with probable reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try it, this way..

function addItem(){

```
var newOpt = $('<option selected="selected">New Option</option>');
$('#select').append(newOpt);
```

}

it works everywhere...

[Check Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ni3net/bUd3v/)